# Rust type alias causes lifetime problems

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to shorten a function signature by introducing a type alias.
The type specification of the parameter looks like this

```
writer: Arc<Mutex<&mut (dyn AsyncWrite + Unpin + Send + Sync)>>  // working
```

which I thought could be shortened by introducing this type alias

```
pub type RefAsyncWriter<'a> = &'a mut (dyn AsyncWrite + Unpin + Send + Sync);
```

so the type parameter becomes just

```
writer: Arc<Mutex<RefAsyncWriter>>  // error[E0726]: implicit elided lifetime not allowed here
```

Unfortunately this change gets me into trouble with lifetimes.

Here I made a brief example

```
use tokio::io::AsyncWrite;
use tokio::fs::File;
use std::sync::{Arc,Mutex};
use std::path::PathBuf;
pub type RefAsyncWriter<'a> = &'a mut (dyn AsyncWrite + Unpin + Send + Sync);

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let f = File::create(PathBuf::from("/tmp/test.txt")).await.unwrap();
    w(Arc::new(Mutex::new(&mut f)));
}

async fn w(writer: Arc<Mutex<RefAsyncWriter>>) {
  // TODO
}
```

The result is the following

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0726]: implicit elided lifetime not allowed here
  --> src/main.rs:13:31
   |
13 | async fn w (writer: Arc<Mutex<RefAsyncWriter>>) {}
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

(see: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb46708a9df66efa0de419a8d98490cf)

If somebody could explain to me (1) if there is a way to get this working and maybe (2) why the type alias actually makes such a difference to the compiler that would be of great help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you introduce an explicit lifetime `'a` in the type alias, you need to specify it when you use this type.

```rust
async fn w<'a>(writer: Arc<Mutex<RefAsyncWriter<'a>>>) {}
```

It seems to work in the playground you provided.

And as the compiler suggests, the anonymous litetime is equivalent.

```rust
async fn w(writer: Arc<Mutex<RefAsyncWriter<'_>>>) {}
```

---

The original version of your function (with the very long type written down after `writer:` is somewhat equivalent to `print1()`, `print2()` and `print3()` in [this documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html).
If you introduce a reference as parameter, then a lifetime parameter necessarily exists for this function; the elision brings just some comfort to save some keystrokes when no confusion is possible about this lifetime.

When defining a type alias containing a reference, the compiler wants us to make the lifetime explicit, probably to prevent someone using this type alias from forgetting that there is a reference *hidden* inside.
Then, using this type alias requires the `<'...>` notation.
But again, when no confusion is possible at usage, the anonymous lifetime `<'_>` saves some keystrokes, avoiding writing `<'a>` twice (after the function name, and in the parameter).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I actually saw the compilers suggestion but I couldn't really figure out where to put the missing lifetime. To be honest, I still don't get why it works this way but in any case that solves my current problem for the moment.

Comment: Yes, it actually makes sense that the compiler forces us to be explicit here in order to not hide a reference inside a type alias. It's a bit confusing at first but at some point even more confusing situations would probably arise if a lifetime was not specified explicitly here. Thanks again for your help.